# web.xml element and web fragments

Tags: java, веб-программирование, web.xml

Всем привет.

1. Хотел узнать для чего нужен такой элемент  metadata-complete в web xml или web fragments?

Нашол обьяснение для такого web xml.. Непонятна выделенная строка.

The web.xml element metadata-complete with a value of true will ignore any other configuration details such as annotations or web fragments. `If the value of this is true or this element is omitted, it will get the configuration details from web fragments and annotations`. However, if any of the web fragment has a value of false for element metadata-complete, the web fragment and its annotations will be ignored.

Сначало вроде всё понятно.

Если такой элемент присваивает значение True для web xml то все другие конфигурации как аннотации и веб фрагменты будут проигнорированны..

Потом пишется - Если такое значение true или такой элемент опушен, web xml достанет конфигурационные детали от web fragments и annotations.

Материал взят из [Syntax and rules for defining web fragments](http://javajee.com/deploying-using-web-fragments-web-fragmentxml).

Непонятно что именно происходит при присваивании значения true для metadata-complete ?

=========================================================================

2. Абсолютно непонятно идея про кофнигурации от множество дескрипторов.

   6,7 по верхней ссылке "Syntax and rules"!

Что значит конфигурации от дескрипторов будут обьеденены ?

Configurations from multiple descriptors will be merged (web.xml or fragments).

*`If the element can take multiple values, the value will be a union`*

**Если элемент принимает множество значений, они обьединятся ?? Как это понимать?**

and if there is a conflict between a web fragment and web.xml, web.xml will take precedence. However, if there is a conflict between two fragments, error is raised.

```
*Elements like welcome-file-list and 
locale-encoding-mapping-list will have their values merged.*

**Непонятна это строка - значения будут слиты, всмысле ??**
```

*For filters and servlets, the value declared in the DD/fragment will only
override the value of any duplicate named parameters, and rest will be merged.*
**О каких значениях идёт речь ?? Для фильтров и сервлетов задаются значения ?**

*The url-pattern and DispatcherType, annotation value is strictly overridden by DD/fragment without any merge.*

*Elements like session-config, jsp-config and login-config may only appear at most once across web.xml and all web fragments.*

*and  may only be declared once for the given  or extension respectively or an error will be raised.*

**Если кто сможет дать ссылку на ресурс обьясняющий ту же тему буду рад..**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Для чего нужен `metadata-complete`

> **The web application deployment descriptor contains a metadata-complete
>   attribute on the web-app element**. The metadata-complete attribute
>   defines whether the web.xml descriptor is complete, or whether other
>   sources of metadata used by the deployment process should be
>   considered. Metadata may come from the web.xml file, web-fragment.xml
>   files, annotations on class files in WEB-INF/classes, and annotations
>   on classes in jar files in the WEB-INF/lib directory. **If
>   metadata-complete is set to "true", the deployment tool only examines
>   the web.xml file and must ignore annotations such as @WebServlet,
>   @WebFilter, and @WebListener present in the class files of the
>   application, and must also ignore any web-fragment.xml descriptor
>   packaged in a jar file in WEB-INF/lib**. If the metadata-complete
>   attribute is not specified or is set to "false", the deployment tool
>   must examine the class files and web-fragment.xml files for
>   metadata,as previously specified.
>
> **The web-fragment.xml also contains the metadata-complete attribute on
>   the web- fragment element**. The attribute defines whether the
>   web-fragment.xml descriptor is complete for the given fragment, or
>   whet her it should scan for annotations in the classes in the
>   associated jar file. **If metadata-complete is set to “true” the
>   deployment tool only examines the web-fragment.xml and must ignore
>   annotations such as @WebServlet , @WebFilter and @WebListener present
>   in the class files of the fragment**. If metadata-complete is not
>   specified or is set to “false” the deployment tool must examine the
>   class files for metadata.

[Servlet 3.1 specification](https://java.net/downloads/servlet-spec/Final/servlet-3_1-final.pdf), п 5.5 Annotations and Resource Injection

2. Непонятно идея про конфигурации от множество дескрипторов

> For better pluggability and less configuration for developers, we
>   introduce the notion of web module deployment descriptor fragments
>   (web fragment). **A web fragment is a part or all of the web.xml that
>   can be specified and included in a library or framework jar's META-INF
>   directory. A plain old jar file in the WEB- INF/lib directory with no
>   web-fragment.xml is also considered a fragment.** Any annotations
>   specified in it will be processed according to the rules defined in
>   8.2.3. The container will pick up and use the configuration as per the rules defined below.
>
> A web fragment is a logical partitioning of the web application in
>   such a way that the frameworks being used within the web application
>   can define all the artifacts without asking developers to edit or add
>   information in the web.xml. **It can include almost all the same
>   elements that the web.xml descriptor uses**.

[Servlet 3.1 specification](https://java.net/downloads/servlet-spec/Final/servlet-3_1-final.pdf), п 8.2.1 Modularity of web.xml

Не стоит пытаться из букв вытянуть знания, которые не требуются вам на практике - запутаетесь окончательно. Лучше попробуйте написать учебный проект с использованием web fragments.

Comment: На данный момент я в рамках создания проекта.